# How to catch an extra in non activity class

Tags: android, kotlin

I am passing an extra from one activity, but since I am learning the MVVM pattern I am trying to catch the extra in the ViewModel of the next activity, parse it, and pass it to such activity, but I haven't found any information about it. My question is, is such thing possible? I have tried the same way that in a regular activity `intent.getSerializableExtra("extraName") as MyObject` but it doesn't work. I have also tried `context.getInintent.getSerializableExtra("extraName") as MyObject` and still no luck :(

Comment: Try using Jackson object mapper. A sample example, String carAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(your object); for better understanding you can follow the documentation

Comment: @RajendraMahato can you show me an example please? I have no idea what you are telling me :( thanks in advance

Comment: try `intent.extras.getParcelable<MyObject>("extraName")`

Comment: First you try yourself, Just go through the documentation, you will understand. After this if you will have doubt just msg me, I will send you a working example.

Comment: but this cannot be used on non activity classes, I have always used on this way on activities intent.getSerializableExtra("extraName") but as soon as I type intent it gets red

Comment: Sorry, yes we cannot use it in non activity class.

Comment: Then try event bus, please go through greenrobot documentation and see some example. It is easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't get an Extra from a viewModel because you can't access the intent. but there are some other ways to do this.

1. you can get the extra in the activity and inject it to the ViewModel via constructor injection(you should use assisted inject library if you are using dagger), or you can inject `saveStateHandle` to the viewModel, then you have access to extras via the handle in the viewmodel(also need assisted inject)
2. you can use an EventBus. EventBus is a publish/subscriber pattern. then you can publish your data from the activity(instead of putting it in the Bundle with `putExtra`) and subscribe to it in the viewModel. there are plenty of different implementations for eventBus using RxJava and ... you can read more about it by googling it.
3. you can use fragments instead of activities and share data between fragments using a sharedViewModel(which might be activitie's viewmodel or if you use navigation component, navGraph's viewmodel). you can google 'share data between fragments' or 'Communicating with fragments' for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful :)